# Uncertainty/Error/Confidence estimation in two-answer polling question

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Let's say I have a two-answer poll, such as:

> In which direction do you stir a cup of coffee?
>
> A: Clockwise
>
> B: Counter-clockwise

and the results are **60%:40% A:B**.

If only 5 people were polled, the chances that the "real" distribution is 50%:50% are quite high.

However, if *one million* people were polled, you could be reasonably sure that the distribution is *not*, in fact, 50%:50%, and there is a significant bias toward clockwise stirrers.

What is the correct way to quantify uncertainty/error/confidence estimation in this situation? How do we quantify how confident to be in a distribution elucidated from a poll question such as this?

Comment: From a frequentist standpoint you could estimate the standard error of the mean and/or a confidence interval for the mean, which would give you a measure of the uncertainty involved, though not of the probability that the population distribution is $50\%:50\%$.

Comment: From a Bayesian standpoint you could start with a prior and update it with your observation to give a posterior distribution for the mean allowing you to calculate a posterior probability of being close to $50\%:50\%$ (though if a continuous distribution it may give $0$ probability of being exactly that)

Comment: So, how specifically would you set up the Bayesian approach to this? Like let's say you start with a prior of a delta-function distributions at 0.5 for each answer (P(A) and P(B)), and you update with each response to the poll? What is the interpretation of P(A|B) or P(B|A) in this context?

Comment: That would not be a good prior: it says there is no possibility of anything other than a $50\%:50\%$ split and no evidence will convince you otherwise.   A more flexible but still symmetric suggestion might be a prior with a beta distribution for the population proportion choosing clockwise of $p$ (so $1-p$ for those choosing counter-clockwise) with density proportional to $p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k-1}$ which with $a$ observations of clockwise and $b$ of  counter-clockwise would give a posterior density proportional to $p^{a+k-1}(1-p)^{b+k-1}$. Often $k=1$ or $k=\frac12$ are chosen to start

Comment: This is great! Thank you!